# C++ template function for derived class with std::is_base_of

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming

I've got problem with creating function that for given type, if it's derived from other one do something and for all other cases do something other. My code:

```
class BaseClass {};
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {};

template <typename T>
void Function(typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value, T>::type && arg) {
    std::cout << "Proper";
}

template <typename T>
void Function(T && arg) {
    std::cout << "Improper";
}

void test() {
    Function(DerivedClass{});
}
```

For class `DeriviedClass` and other based on `BaseClass` I'd like to call function *couting* `Proper`, but it *couts* `Improper`. Any suggestions?

Comment: T is in non-deduced context here, move enable_if to the result type: `auto Function(T) -> typename enable_if<???, void>::type`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to the question, SFINAE expressions won't work the way you did it.
It should be instead something like this:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value>::type
Function(T && arg) {
    std::cout << "Proper" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<not std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value>::type
Function(T && arg) {
    std::cout << "Improper" << std::endl;
}
```

SFINAE expressions will enable or disable `Function` depending on the fact that `BaseClass` is base of `T`. Return type is `void` in both cases, for it's the default type for `std::enable_it` if you don't define it.
See it on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90b1c1db04c6a2c5).

Other valid alternatives exist and some of them have been mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Is there possibility now to overload that function for specific type, e.g. float?

Comment: @miqelm overloaded non-template functions are preferred over template ones, thus yes (see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b49a7e7f56954978) as an example).

Comment: Are you sure? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if notes said me that you are wrong

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass {};
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {};
class OtherClass {};

template <typename T,typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value, T>::type>
void Function(T && arg)
{
  std::cout << "Proper" << std::endl;
}

void Function(...)
{
  std::cout << "Improper"<< std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  Function(DerivedClass{});
  Function(BaseClass{});
  Function(OtherClass{});
}
```

Comment: `Function<OtherClass, void>(OtherClass{});` can be used to break it easily. Too weak a solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T>
auto Function(T && arg) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value>::type 
{
    std::cout << "Proper";
}

template <typename T>
auto Function(T && arg) -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<BaseClass, T>::value>::type 
{
    std::cout << "Improper";
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EyjDoZY4zvxnlSzM)

Answer (score 1):

C++11+ :

```
#include <type_traits> // for is_base_of<>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

class NotDerived {};

template<typename Class>
void foo(const Class& cls)
{
  static_assert(is_base_of<Base, Class>::value, "Class doesn't inherit from Base!");
  // The codes...
}

int main()
{
  foo(Derived()); // OK!
  foo(NotDerived()); // Error!

  return 0;
}
```