# How do I check if a variable derives from a class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to print variables of many types. I've made a class named `IStringable`, and some classes that derive from it. In my `PrintVariable` function I want to check whether the parameter derives from `IStringable`, and if it does then print it.

```
class IStringable {
public:
    virtual ~IStringable() { }
    virtual std::string ToString() const = 0;
}

class Person : public IStringable {
public:
    Person(const std::string name) : _name(name) { }
    virtual std::string ToString() const { return _name; }
private:
    std::string _name;
}

// This does not work as intended, as I don't know how it could be implemented
template <>
void PrintVariable<IStringable>(const IStringable& var) {
    std::cout << var.ToString() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Person p("Foo");
    PrintVariable(p);
}
```

So far I've worked around this problem by just using `std::cout << p.ToString() << std::endl;` instead, but I'm wondering if there's a better solution to this.

Comment: Simple `void PrintVariable(const IStringable& var) {}` will do what you expect. If you try to pass something not derived from `IStringable` to this function, compiler will stop you from doing that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ template function for derived class with std::is\_base\_of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085326/c-template-function-for-derived-class-with-stdis-base-of)

Comment: you want `PrintVariable` to be callable also with an instance that is not deriving from `IStringable` ? what should the function do in that case?

Comment: Yes. If `PrintVariable` is called on, e.g. an `int` it should use `std::string()` on that int in order to convert it to a `std::string` so it can be used in `std::cout`

Comment: I dont dare to write this as an answer, but I think your approach is fundamentally flawed. Requesting each type to inherit from `IStringable` is quite intrusive and not really needed. You typically provide an overload for `operator<<` to be able to print something. On the other hand if you want to stay with the interface then I would still go for the `operator<<` that can call the corresponding `ToString` instead of your `PrintVariable`

Comment: I would be able to do that, but it would be harder to write a bool since it needs to be converted to string.

Comment: @GuySimonsen you dont need to convert a bool to string by yourself if you use the streams [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) modifier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a template:

```
void PrintVariable(const IStringable& var) {
    std::cout << var.ToString() << '\n';
}
```

Only calls to `PrintVariable` with object convertible to `IStringable` are legal:

```
Person p("Alice");
struct Bob {} b;
PrintVariable(p); // OK
PrintVariable(b); // ill-formed: no conversion from Bob to const IStringable&
```

Additionally, you could redesign `PrintVariable` as an operator:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, IStringable const& rhs)
{
    return os << rhs.ToString();
}
```

So you could write:

```
Person p("Alice");
std::cout << p << '\n';
```

---

As it appears from comments, OP whants a way to log things. A minimal implementation would be:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

namespace Logger
{
    struct IStringable
    {
        virtual ~IStringable() {}
        virtual std::string ToString() const = 0;
    };

    std::string to_string(IStringable const& v) { return v.ToString(); }

    void log(std::string_view const& sv)
    {
        std::cout << "debug: " << sv << '\n';
    }
    template<class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_convertible_v<T, std::string_view>, int> = 0>
    void log(T const& v)
    {
        using std::to_string;
        log(to_string(v));
    }
}
```

The idea is to use [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) and [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to call either `std::to_string` or `ISrtingable::ToString` on the thing to log, and log the resultant string.

Usage:

```
class Person : public Logger::IStringable {
public:
    Person(const std::string name) : _name(name) { }
    virtual std::string ToString() const { return _name; }
private:
    std::string _name;
};

int main()
{
    Person p("Alice");
    double d = 0.0;
    const char* c = "Some words";

    Logger::log(p);
    Logger::log(d);
    Logger::log(c);
}
```

Demo: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77e19e87c9d4780d